# Ansible blocks: Re-raising errors in `rescue` block

Tags: error-handling, ansible

I'm new to Ansible so I'm probably approaching this incorrectly, but I'm trying to find a way to re-raise an error once it has been `rescue`d by a block.

The purpose of this is to be able to log failed tasks to an API before terminating the playbook. I would use the `always` section, but then the `ansible_failed_task` and `ansible_failed_result` variables are not populated.

I'm fairly confident that my approach is wrong, so how would an experienced Ansible dev handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to do, this is a basic (non functional) illustration of how I would manage that. The key is using the [`fail` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fail_module.html) to end playbook in rescue phase after handling the error the way you wish.

```
- name: handle error nicely in my block
  block:

    - name: This is my task that can fail
      debug:
        msg: "I'm a a task that can fail"
      register: some_var

  rescue:

    - name: Do whatever you need to log the failure
      debug:
        msg: "I'm a log task playing around with some_var: {{ some_var }}"

    - name: fail the playbook as the task was not successful
      fail:
        msg: "The task was not successful. Aborting"
```

Does this scenario meet your expectations ?

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator! Yes that makes sense. Is it possible to fail with the original error though? I guess I'm thinking about it programmatically - if I wanted to do this in Python I'd catch the Exception then raise it again once I was done logging. I assume I am just missing knowledge of Ansible idioms?

Comment: Just explore `some_var` which will contain the info you need and write out whatever you like. Note that the original failure will always be present in the output.

Comment: Ansible provides the following variables in rescue blocks to help with this: ansible_failed_task (to get the name use ansible_failed_task.name)
ansible_failed_result

Answer (score 4):

from ansible [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#handling-errors-with-blocks) (see last section)

> New in version 2.1.

> Ansible provides a couple of variables for tasks in the rescue portion of a block:
>
> - **ansible_failed_task**
>   The task that returned ‘failed’ and triggered the rescue. For example, to get the name >use ansible_failed_task.name.
> - **ansible_failed_result**
>   The captured return result of the failed task that triggered the rescue. This would >equate to having used this var in the register keyword.

So here is an example:

```
- name: expample
  hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - block: 
     - debug:
         msg: some random task      

     - name: a failing task
       fail:
         msg: "i failed "
            
    rescue:
      - debug:
         msg: the failed task in the block is {{ ansible_failed_task }}. the result of the task is {{ansible_failed_result}}
```